# NASM tutorial uses int 80h, but this isn't working on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm starting NASM Assembler after finishing FASM. I'm coding this in a Windows Operating System. 
My code reads:

```
section.data ;Constant
            msg:    db "Hello World!"
            msg_L:   equ $-msg  ; Current - msg1

section.bss ;Varialble

section.text ; Code
        global _WinMain@16 

_WinMain@16:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1; Where to wrte it out. Terminal
        mov ecx, msg
        mov edx, msg_L
        int 80h

        mov eax, 1 ; EXIT COMMAND
        mov ebx,0 ; No Eror
        int 80h
```

To compile it and execute I use:

```
nasm -f win32 test.asm -o test.o
ld test.o -o test.exe
```

I am currently following this video on tutorials on NASM. I changed the start to WIN32, but when I execute it, it just gets stuck and won't run... Any problems with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to make a Linux system call (`int 80h`) on the Windows operating system.

This will not work. You need to call Windows API functions. For example, [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) will display a message box on the screen.

```
section .rdata   ; read-only Constant data
            msg:    db "Hello World!"
            msg_L:   equ $-msg  ; Current - msg1

section .text ; Code
        global _WinMain@16
        extern _MessageBoxA@16

_WinMain@16:
        ; Display a message box
        push 40h   ; information icon
        push 0
        push msg
        push 0
        call _MessageBoxA@16

        ; End the program
        xor eax, eax
        ret
```

Make sure that the book/tutorial you're reading is about *Windows* programming with NASM, not Linux programming!

Comment: One question. Can i compile it on my Linux VM, and then send over the .o file to windows and work fine?

Comment: No. You can compile it on your Linux VM and *run* it on your Linux VM, but you can't run it on Windows because there are no Linux system calls on Windows. @dsafds

Comment: Why cant i compile it in my Linux VM? It works for him:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uca_zY8ZNpA (Ubuntu BTW)

Comment: He is doing everything in Ubuntu. That's Linux. It works fine there. It will not work on Windows. When you try to run it on Windows, it fails, because `int 80h` is not a supported operation in the Windows operating system.

Comment: You can compile it in linux (or in windows). You can also link it in linux and windows (with appropriate linker and system libraries). But your binary will be only for linux or only windows, thus it has to be run in that OS. If you have good tutorials for NASM under linux, and you have linux in VM, just use it, skip windows.

Comment: Wait i have one more important question.. When i make OS and Kernel, would int 80h be available then(im thinking no)?

Comment: No, in your own OS and kernel you may make some of BIOS calls available (int 10h), everything else in tutorials (int 80h, syscall, int 21h, WIN API) is part of other operating systems.

Comment: No. The `int` instruction issues a system call interrupt. Interrupt 80h is the `syscall` interrupt on Unix-based systems, provided by the kernel. If there's no Unix kernel, there's nothing implementing this. You have to implement the functionality yourself. You can issue interrupt 80h, but it won't do anything useful. Start small; your first project in assembly should not be writing an OS kernel.